# Interpolate text getting NULL in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been trying to use the code given in a class, but it didn't seem to work. The idea is that, when I put a name, it goes on when called, but i keep getting "null". Even, I saw the teacher using "%1$s" and ""%1$s" in two different lines to make the work done, but none seems to work in my code.

Here it goes the 2 pages of code and an image of the null

The activity:

```
private void loadPage(int i) {
        mPaginaActiva = mContenidos.getPage(i);
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mPaginaActiva.getImageId());
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        String pageText=mPaginaActiva.getText();
        //acá interpolamos el nombre
        pageText=String.format(pageText, mNombre);

        mTextView.setText(pageText);
```

The content:

```
private Pagina[] mPaginas;

    public Contenidos(){
        mPaginas = new Pagina[8];

        mPaginas[0] = new Pagina(
                R.drawable.img0,
                "Saludos \"%1$s, acá empieza tu viaje.",
                new Opcion("Entrenarme", 1),
                new Opcion("Luchar", 2)
        );
        mPaginas[1] = new Pagina(
                R.drawable.img1,
                "Hazte experto en el manejo de una de estas armas.",
                new Opcion("Elijo el palo", 3),
                new Opcion("Elijo la espada", 4)
        );
        mPaginas[4] = new Pagina(
                R.drawable.img4,
                "Bien %1$s, has elegido aprender a usar la espada. Ahora Suzuki está despistado. ¿Deseas atacar por sorpresa?",
                new Opcion("Quiero luchar con honor", 5),
                new Opcion("Atacar por la espalda", 2)
        );
```

:[image: Null Error]

Also, if possible, I would like to know if there is a chance to get GIFs instead of images, since the img0 - img7 are GIFs, but they aint getting the animation done in the app. This part of the code is in the content and I'm using drawable:

```
mPaginas[4] = new Pagina(
                    R.drawable.img4,
```

Comment: Is `mNombre` `null`?

Comment: I have tried to put different names there, but they all come as null all the time